# Do I have to buy a domain in order to run my app that is using an EC2 instance on AWS server in order to use HTTPS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, lamp

I have an iOS app on TestFlight that is using a LAMP server running on an EC2 Instance on AWS. It has an elastic IP, and therefore has a Public DNS: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

So currently from the app itself I run commands directly through the elastic IP like so:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/API/SignIn.php?username=\(username)");
```

Now this works great, however I want to start moving everything to HTTPS.

So I was hoping to go about it like so, using the public DNS:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/API/SignIn.php?username=\(username)");
```

But this method keeps shouting at me:

> "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server
>   cannot be made"

So far what I've done is the openSSL process, I created a certificate and key, and I put it in the apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ServerAlias www.ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/key.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course I have the security groups set to HTTPS port 443.

The HTTPS *is* in fact accessible from say Safari, but obviously it is still not a *trusted* website.

I tried going through the CertBot free path - but they cannot allow an SSL certificate for AWS created domains (understandable, they aren't too reliable and change often).

I also tried going through AWS itself, created a certificate in the Certificate Manager (it was approved and Issued to me), but then when I tried to use it in the Load Balancer - but the certificate just doesn't show up there (maybe I'm doing it wrong, I tried many ways but it just doesn't seem to work)

I would really love to go about this without having to purchase a domain, but right now I don't see any other way. Does anyone know of another way?

### Edit

Also I'd rather AVOID the part where I tell iOS to ignore the security, because I don't want Apple to reject my app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: You can use the domain that your ISP has assigned to your IP. You can also run the LAMP server yourself.

Comment: What domain did you generate a certificate for in AWS Certificate Manager, if you don't own any domains?

Comment: @MarkB I generated it on ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: Oh you uploaded a self-signed cert into ACM, you didn't ask ACM to generate one for your domain. If you don't want to use a self-signed cert then you will have to purchase a domain, since you can't request a valid SSL cert for a domain that you don't own. Note, this isn't an AWS limitation, it is an SSL limitation.

Comment: If you have access to any domain at all, you could create a subdomain.

Comment: @MarkB I see, yeah figures AWS will know the difference. Oh well. Thank you!

Comment: @halfer I do have access to a domain, I am currently using it on ANOTHER EC2 instance that I have under the same AWS account. However that domain is used for a general website (Wordpress) for information about the APP. But I was hesitant to use it for the APP server since I thought it might be a security risk if people associate the APP website with the Server Domain.

Comment: Can you create a subdomain? Using it elsewhere does not preclude creating a new domain, unless you don't want to draw attention to the common control/ownership.

Comment: @halfer Yeah I'd rather not give people out there any ideas of where to begin hacking lol. Like I said, I can do it for now cause it's not in the App Store yet, and I'm pretty sure most of the people this app will be good for are usually not hackers, but still. I'd rather just buy a domain to reduce that risk. Thank you though! I might use it just to make sure everything works well and change it in the future

Comment: Ah, if you are building something that will go into the App Store, then I'd assert that the cost of another domain is fairly trivial!

Answer (score 0):

Use

> URLSessionDelegate

to trust the certificate if you are using URLSession to perfomr the request and implement the following func

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    print("delegate call")
    if challenge.protectionSpace.host == "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com" {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    } else {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}
```

to trust the certification since SSl Ocurred because the sing of the certificaction has a mistmatch. if your are using Alamofire to perform the request ten use version 4.7 because version 5 is not posible yet to truth a not valid certificate.